# Easy access to instagram users public profile

Tags: rest, instagram, instagram-api

I'm building an simple osx app, that will fetch my follower count and other public available stats from my instagram-user, and keep statistics on them. I'm know that there is a method for getting user data throught the API, like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

*But I would like to avoid the hassle of getting the access token...*

I know that there are ways around the API for getting other public information, like getting a users recent media:

```
https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/media/
```

**Does anyone know a similar method for getting a users public profile information, like follows- an followers-count and number of posts?**

Comment: you need to pass with approval process due to,
Instagram updated there api process:  http://instagram.com/developer

Comment: Yeah, and officially i would need to go through the authentication to get media too, but there is a workaround, so I though that there were a workaround for getting public profile data too.. But according to you there are no workaround?

Comment: @Wiingaard. Is there any workaround? did you find the way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery